# Problem with Portable Hard Drives

Tags: hardware

I am a new Ubuntu user running 13.10.2 and I am trying to transfer the files from my previous computer, a Macbook, over. They are stored on two different portable hard drives.

I am having a huge amount of difficulty with this. Almost every single file has a different problem.

Many of the jpgs are labled jpeg, refuse to be renamed and won't open with any image program. When I click them they say:

Failed to open input stream for file.

They can't be renamed and when I try to put them onto the computer they say:

Error while copying "file"

Error opening file: Permission denied

Every video file on the drive seems to need a different set of plug-ins which I don't know how to get. From Advanced Streaming Format (ASF) demuxers to MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoders and On2 VP6/Flash decoders. Seemingly an endless stream of different updates.

Some of the word documents are showing up as Zip Archives which, predictably, extract into a pile of useless files. Some of the other word files do not do this.

I am slowly working my way through these problems one by one, but there are so many issues I think I must be going about this in a fundamentally wrong-headed way. Is there something I have to do to make Ubuntu work with my drives?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming these on your Mac or in Ubuntu? I'd try it on the Mac first and then move everything over.

For your audio codecs and drivers, open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Also, according to [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/FAQ) Rhythmbox uses gstreamer. According to [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/asf/index.html?gi-language=c) the  "ASF demuxer" is provided by the gstreamer "ugly" plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

As for the Word documents, save them as .odf files, then you can use them in LibreOffice.

Hope this is helpful! PM me if you have further questions... I'd be happy to help!

source